# How to draw a spherical triangle on a sphere in 3D?

Tags: python, blender

Suppose you know the three vertices for a spherical triangle. 
Then how do you draw the sides on a sphere in 3D?

I need some python code to use in Blender 3d modelisation software.

I already have the sphere done in 3D in Blender.

Thanks & happy blendering.

note  1:

i have the 3 points / vertices (p1,p2,p3 ) on the sphere for a spherical triangle
but i need to trace the edges  on the sphere in 3D

so what would be the equations needed to determine  all vertices  between each points pair of the triangle on the sphere
3 edges  from p1 to p2  -  p2 to p3  and o3  to p1

i know it has something to do with the Great circle   for Geodesic  on a sphere
but cannot   find the proper equations to do the calculations in spherical coordinates!

Thanks

---

Great circles

it   would  have been interesting to see a solution with great circle and see tehsolution in spherical coordinates directly !

but still interesting to do it in the euclidiens space

Thanks

---

ok i used this idea of line segment between 2 points

but did not do it as  indicated before

i used an alternative method - Bezier line interpolation**

i parametrize the line with a bezier line
then subdivided  and calculated as shonw ealier the ratio and angle for each of the subdivided bezier point on the chord
and it works very well and very precise

but it would be interesting to see how it is done whit the earlier method
but not certain how to do the iteration loop?

how do you load up the python code  here
just past it  with Ctrl-V?

Thanks and happy 2.5

---

i do use the blenders' forum
but no guaranti to get a clear answer all the time!

that's why i tried here - took a chance

i did the first edge seems to work 
now got to make a loop to  get  multi segment for first edge and then do the other edges also

2- other subject
  i open here a post on bezier triangle patch
 i know it's not a usfull tool
but just to show how it is done
have youeseen a python sript to do theses triangel patch
and i did ask this questin on blender's foum and no answer
also on IRC python and sems to be dead right now 
probably guys are too busy finishing the 2.5 Beta vesion which should come out  in a week or 2

Hey Thanks a lot  for this math discussion 
if i have problem be back tomorrow

happy math and 2.5

Answer (score 4):

### Create Sine Mesh

Python code to create a sine wave mesh in Blender:

```
import math
import Blender
from Blender import NMesh

x = -1 * math.pi

mesh = NMesh.GetRaw()
vNew = NMesh.Vert( x, math.sin( x ), 0 )
mesh.verts.append( vNew )

while x < math.pi:
 x += 0.1
 vOld = vNew
 vNew = NMesh.Vert( x, math.sin( x ), 0 )
 mesh.verts.append( vNew )
 mesh.addEdge( vOld, vNew )

NMesh.PutRaw( mesh, "SineWave", 1 )
Blender.Redraw()
```

The code's explanation is at: http://davidjarvis.ca/blender/tutorial-04.shtml

### Algorithm to Plot Edges

Drawing one line segment is the same as drawing three, so the problem can be restated as:

> How do you draw an arc on a sphere,
>   given two end points?

In other words, draw an arc between the following two points on a sphere:

- P<sub>1</sub> = (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>1</sub>)
- P<sub>2</sub> = (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>, z<sub>2</sub>)

Solve this by plotting many mid-points along the arc P<sub>1</sub>P<sub>2</sub> as follows:

1. Calculate the radius of the sphere:
   `R = sqrt( x12 + y12 + z12 )`
2. Calculate the mid-point (<sub>m</sub>) of the line between P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub>:
   `Pm = (xm, ym, zm)
   xm = (x1 + x2) / 2
   ym = (y1 + y2) / 2
   zm = (z1 + z2) / 2`
3. Calculate the length to the mid-point of the line between P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub>:
   `Lm = sqrt( xm2, ym2, zm2 )`
4. Calculate the ratio of the sphere's radius to the length of the mid-point:
   `k = R / Lm`
5. Calculate the mid-point along the arc:
   `Am = k * Pm = (k * xm, k * ym, k * zm)`

For P<sub>1</sub> to P<sub>2</sub>, create two edges:

- P<sub>1</sub> to A<sub>m</sub>
- A<sub>m</sub> to P<sub>2</sub>

The two edges will cut through the sphere. To solve this, calculate the mid-points between P<sub>1</sub>A<sub>m</sub> and A<sub>m</sub>P<sub>2</sub>. The more mid-points, the more closely the line segments will follow the sphere's surface.

As Blender is rather precise with its calculations, the resulting arc will likely be (asymptotically) hidden by the sphere. Once you have created the triangular mesh, move it away from the sphere by a few units (like 0.01 or so).

### Use a Spline

Another solution is to create a [spline](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/bpy.types.Spline.html) from the following:

- sphere's radius (calculated as above)
- P<sub>1</sub>
- A<sub>m</sub>
- P<sub>2</sub>

The resulting splines must be moved in front of the sphere.

### Blender Artists Forums

The [Blender experts](http://blenderartists.org/forum/) will also have great ideas on how to solve this; try asking them.

### See Also

http://www.mathnews.uwaterloo.ca/Issues/mn11106/DotProduct.php

http://cr4.globalspec.com/thread/27311/Urgent-Midpoint-of-Arc-formula

Comment: i can   program it in   python !

i have problem with the math equations to dertermine the triangle's edges on the 3D sphere 

in othe words what  how do you calculate the location of vertice on the sphere for each edge of the triangle ?

hope it's clear now

Thanks

Comment: @Ricky: Let me know if you have not plotted the triangle, yet.

Answer (score 0):

One cheap and easy method for doing this would be to create the triangle and subdivide the faces down to the level of detail you want, then normalize all the vertices to the radius you want.

Comment: the problem is with math in 3D in spherical coordinates

 what are the equations  to calculate the vertices location function of the triangle's side on the sphere?

i know it has something to do with the grreat circle  but how do you calculate theses great circles ?


Thanks

Comment: @Ricky: You do not need great circles; you can use the ratio of mid-point lengths to the sphere's radius.